# MySQL LEFT JOIN with GROUP BY and WHERE clause query

Tags: sql, left-join

Tables that look like bellow

[image: SQL Tables]

How to write SQL Query to read all department names with an employee count salary > 1000, if a department not found in employee we required to show as zero counts in output.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? How to select departments? How to count employees? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please refrain from using images. While this one is pretty clear and readable, it still doesn't allow people to copy and paste it relevant information from it, people with limited (mobile) data might've turned images off, or images might simply not view properly on smaller (mobile) devices. Your table structures can definitely be written in a code block instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `left join` and aggregation:

```
select d.name, count(e.id)
from departments d left join
     employees e
     on e.department_id = d.id and e.salary >= 10000
group by d.name
```

Comment: The important part here is the `on` clause. The condition needs to go there, rather than in a `where` clause, for the empty groups to appear with zero counts - otherwise they will be missing. I've been struggling with this same issue for the past two hours and I finally stumbled across this post! 